# QRegExp format for finding the strings which contains one new line character '\n' and arbitrary count spaces ' '

Tags: c++, regex, qt, qregexp, reg-expressionvalidator

How to write QRegExp  pattern for finding the strings which contains one new line character '\n' and arbitrary count spaces ' '?

Comment: That sounds rather straight-forward. What pattern did you come up with?

Comment: The pattern  like "smth.  /n     smth."

Comment: So, you wrote `"\n "`? What is the input string and the expected result?